# Converting curl to URL request in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, curl

The curl request example is as follows, I am having trouble converting it to a url request in swift.

```
curl --include --request POST \
--header "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
--data-binary "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=PUBLIC_KEY&client_secret=PRIVATE_KEY" \
'https://api.tcgplayer.com/token'
```

This is how I think it should look like but it isnt working as I am expecting.

```
 guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.tcgplayer.com/token") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  
    request.addValue("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=\(TCGPlayerClient.publicKey)&client_secret=\(TCGPlayerClient.privateKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "data-binary")
```

Comment: You need to set the `httpBody` data and not send it as a new header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding the binary data as a header, instead you should convert the string to data and add it to the `httpBody` property of the request.

```
request.httpBody = "YOUR STRING HERE".data(using: .utf8)
```