# Convert Postman GET curl to swift url session request

Tags: ios, swift, curl, get, urlsession

I am having trouble converting the following curl to a url request in swift.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://p52.pocket52.com/apis/v1?p={%22x%22:%22images%22,%22pl%22:{}}'
```

I Tried the following way, but I got  Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://p52.pocket52.com/apis/v1?p={%22x%22:%22images%22,%22pl%22:{}}")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
```

I tried with the solution present in this link [Converting curl to URL request in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760182/converting-curl-to-url-request-in-swift)

but this is a POST curl it doesn't works for GET curl, Since GET request should not contains a body.

Let me define it more clearly, Basically I need to frame the following GET request.

```
https://p52.xxxx.com/apis/v1?p={"x":"images","pl":""}
```

We can achieve it by attaching a swift dictionary for a URLComponent part but, hear I am having a nested dictionary that's where I am facing difficulty.

Comment: could it be the exclamation mark after the url?

Comment: @Turo that's the reason why its giving error, but how can we make it to work. One way is we can use guard to avoid the crash, but that is not the final solution, I am getting the response from the server with that curl in post man, and how can we make it in swift?

Comment: did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-do-i-make-an-http-request-in-swift and its answers?

Comment: Yeah, all of this are how do we make, get and post request in swift, for my case the difficulty exist to make the following url in swift https://p52.pocket52.com/apis/v1?p={"x":"images","pl":{}}

Comment: my last shot: looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723912/swift-get-request-with-parameters , too? As you see, I'm clueless, too.

Comment: @Turo, thank you for the help, I tried this too but no luck, the complexity exist to add a nested dictionary params in a url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724627/6791677) like @Turo suggested and build your `URL` using `URLComponents`, like so:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://p52.pocket52.com/apis/v1")
components?.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "p", value: #"{"x": "images", "pl" : ""}"#)
]
```

Then use the `url` property of `URLComponents` to compose your `URLRequest`:

```
guard let url = components?.url else { return }
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
```